# How to retrieve Single result from google?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-search, google-search-platform

I am developing the android application in which user gives the key to search that key has to be search in google and read the output of google (like google voice search).
The google gives the multiple results as per the key but i need only first result among the all results fetched by the google.

How can i do this?

Is there any references?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the argument `num=1`, i.e.:

```
https://www.google.pt/search?num=1&q=test
```